# Django show product detail in POPUP using ajax,jquery

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

I am new learn in django-ajax . I don't no how to use popup ajax in django view. I create two html files `list.html` and `detail.html`.

My question is when I open `list.html` whenever I click on any product to show the product details using popup format using ajax.

So please tell what are the changes required in view, jquery, html and ajax

**view.py**

```
def show_product(request, product_slug,  template_name="catalog/product.html"):
  p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug) 
  categories = p.categories.filter(is_active=True) 
  page_title = p.name 
  meta_keywords = p.meta_keywords 
  meta_description = p.meta_description 
  return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),context)

def list_product(request):
  queryset_list = Product.objects.all() #.order_by("-timestamp")
  paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page
  page_request_var = "page"
  page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
  try:
      queryset = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
      queryset = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
      queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
   context = {
    "object_list": queryset, 
    "name": "List",
    "page_request_var": page_request_var
  }
  return render(request, "catalog/list.html", context)
```

**list.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="signup">
  <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
     <center><h1>{{ name }}</h1></center>
     {% for obj in object_list %}
     <div class="caption">
          <h3>{{ obj.name }}</h3>
          <p>{{ obj.content|linebreaks|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
          <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="pagination">
       <span class="step-links">
       {% if object_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
       {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ object_list.number }} of {{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if object_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**product.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} 
<body>
<div class="signup">
    <h1>{{ p.name }}</h1> 
    Brand: <em>{{ p.brand }}</em> <br/><br/> 
    SKU: {{ p.sku }} <br/> <br/> 
    In categor{{ categories.count|pluralize:"y,ies" }}:  
    {% for c in categories %} 
        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a> 
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %} <br/><br/> 
    {% if p.sale_price %} 
        Was: <del>$ {{ p.old_price }}</del> <br/> 
        Now: $ {{ p.price }} 
    {% else %} 
        Price: $ {{ p.price }} 
    {% endif %} <br/><br/> 
    <div class="cb"><br /><br/></div> 
    <h3>Product Description</h3> 
        {{ p.description }}    
</div> 
</body>
{% endblock content %}
```